# Is it possible to classify all the inequivalent classes of first order sentence with quantifier rank fixed

Tags: lo.logic, formal-languages

It is known that for symbols with finite many relations, the number of inequivalent class of first order sentence with quantifier rank $m$ is finite. But is it possible to list (classify) them? At least in special cases.

Comment: The number is roughly a tower of exponentials of height $m$, so there is not enough paper in the universe to list them for $m$ larger than a very, very small constant.

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773942/is-there-way-to-classify-the-quantifier-rank-m-first-order-sentence-in-first-o/774004#774004